# Permanently set a hint?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an edit text  and I want when the user puts his name for example for the hint to permanently change when he has inserted his name.Am I supposed to do this onCreate? and if yes I'm supposed to do something like `if(name.isEmpty())?`

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/hintguy"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
            app:errorEnabled="true">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/texto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="#4249ff"
                android:hint="@string/BtnO"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="confirmInput"
            android:text="@string/Btns" />
```

here is my java code

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        prefs= getSharedPreferences("my_data",MODE_PRIVATE);
        String name = prefs.getString("MY_NAME","name");
        String home = prefs.getString("MY_HOME","home");
        nameInput =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.texto);
        homeInput =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textd);
        Toast.makeText(this,name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

    public void copy(View view) {
    }

    public void confirmInput(View view) {
        String name=nameInput.getText().toString();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("MY_NAME",name);
        editor.apply();
        Toast.makeText(this,name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        TextInputLayout textInputLayout = (TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.hintguy);
        textInputLayout.setHint("Hello");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this in onCreate. you need to check if theres a name in prefs before setting the hint.

```
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = (TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.hintguy);
String savedName=prefs.getString("MY_NAME","");
if (savedName.length()>0){
textInputLayout.setHint("Hello "+name);
}else{
textInputLayout.setHint("hint when no name present");
}
```

If something is found under the "MY_NAME" key in shared preferences then that something will be set in the hint. else you get the random hint. check this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences#getString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). try it out i hope it works